# Filtering max/min values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
Player  Attempt Score
John    A       10
John    B       20
Mary    A       5
Mary    B       10
```

How can I transform the dataframe so only the maximum or minimum score for each player in each attempt is displayed?

In the maximum case the result would look like this:

```
Player  Attempt Score
John    B       20
Mary    B       10
```

Comment: Since someone has decided to answer despite the question being closed, here's a shorter/better answer: `df.iloc[df.groupby('Player').Score.idxmax()]`

Comment: Note that `idxmax` only returns the *first* maximum value. Different but not better. So you have 2 options depending on whether you want duplicates or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way using `groupby` + `transform`. The marked duplicate has more verbose variations.

```
res = df[df['Score'] == df.groupby('Player')['Score'].transform('max')]

print(res)

  Player Attempt  Score
1   John       B     20
3   Mary       B     10
```